# How to write if ($row_login['vstatus'] != 'verified' OR "reconized' && $_POST['amount'] >20) {

Tags: php, if-statement

Been trying different styles even pipe but seems not to be working. want to write the statement below:

```
if ($row_login['vstatus'] != 'verified' OR 'recognized' && $_POST['amount'] >20)    {
```

Plz help

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can compare one thing to many others, if you do it a little different:

```
if(!in_array($row_login['vstatus'], array('verified', 'recognized')) && $_POST['amount'] >20)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I got the logic right it should be:

```
if (($row_login['vstatus'] != 'verified' && $row_login['vstatus'] !='recognized') && $_POST['amount'] >20){

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a little tricky part in the logic of the question - `var != (A or B)` is the same as `var != A and var != B`. Nicely spotted though.

Comment: @Martin deleted old comments that are not no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare one thing to two others. Use something like this:

```
if ($row_login['vstatus'] != 'verified' && $row_login['vstatus'] != 'recognized' && $_POST['amount'] >20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like so:

```
 if ($row_login['vstatus'] != 'verified' || $row_login['vstatus'] != 'recognized' && $_POST['amount'] >20)  {
```

and yes, I think you may have actually wanted to do it as @Martin suggested